# time package `nsec()` function

Tags: go, time

I'm confused about the time package `nsec()` function operation. It's applying the `AND` operator on the `wall` property of the time & nanosecond mask (which is 1<<30-1 => 111111111111111111111111111111) to return the nanosecond value of the time object. I'm wondering that `ANDING` a number with `1<<30-1`  equals the number (because all digits have value 1), so why they're doing it?

```golang
func (t *Time) nsec() int32 {
    return int32(t.wall & nsecMask)
}
```

The main source code:
https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.7:src/time/time.go;l=164;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.16.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wall` field is of type uint64 and it contains more than just
nanoseconds:

```
// From high to low bit position, wall encodes a 1-bit flag (hasMonotonic),
// a 33-bit seconds field, and a 30-bit wall time nanoseconds field.
```

So what they're doing here is that they're extracting last 30 bits to
get nanoseconds.